# How to create a wrapper connected app for SOAP usage when API whitelistin is active?

Tags: soap, connected-apps

We have recently activated API access control for connected apps. This was a new feature from Spring '15 to have control which app can connect through the API instead of using the API enabled profile setting, which allows access through any app.

All apps which are listed as a connected app has automatically access. The problem is that the access restriction is now also active on the SOAP API. So, our SOAP API calls through the AJAX Toolkit fails.

How can I now create a "wrapper" connected app for the SOAP API ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the [Control Individual API Client Access to Your Salesforce Organization](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_security_api_control.htm) feature?

Some applicable bits from the release notes:

> With API Client Whitelisting, an administrator can approve or block individual client application access for each associated connected app. All client applications that are not configured as connected apps are denied access. If you are not using connected apps, you can relax this restriction for individual users by assigning them a profile or permission set with “Use Any API Client” enabled.
>
> > Contact Salesforce to enable API Client Whitelisting. After it’s enabled, all client access is restricted until explicitly allowed by the administrator. This restriction might block access to applications that your users are already using. Before you enable this feature, you should configure and approve connected apps for any client applications you want users to continue using, or give the users a profile or permission set with “Use Any API Client” enabled.

It sounds like you will need to give the users the "Use Any API Client" API permission. Either via their profile or via a permission set.